# using template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

Usual template structs can be specialized, e.g.,

```
template<typename T>
struct X{};

template<>
struct X<int>{};
```

C++11 gave us the new cool `using` syntax for expressing template typedefs:

```
template<typename T>
using YetAnotherVector = std::vector<T>
```

Is there a way to define a template specialization for these using constructs similar to specializations for struct templates? I tried the following:

```
template<>
using YetAnotherVector<int> = AFancyIntVector;
```

but it yielded a compile error. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: AFAIK, you do need a backend class for it. Hide away a specialized `struct` and then make the alias using that class.

Comment: Not sure if I follow, what's wrong with `typedef YetAnotherVector<int> AFancyIntVector` ?

Comment: @Mr.kbok: Using your statement together with the using results in a compile error "multiple types in one declaration"

Comment: @Mr.kbok, The OP wants `YetAnotherVector<T>` to be `std::vector<T>`, but `YetAnotherVector<int>` to be `AFancyIntVector`.

Comment: chris: Okay, I got it the other way around. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.

But you can define the alias as:

```
template<typename T>
using YetAnotherVector = typename std::conditional<
                                     std::is_same<T,int>::value, 
                                     AFancyIntVector, 
                                     std::vector<T>
                                     >::type;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `std::conditional` has now kicked my butt so many times I've lost count.

Comment: Maybe because it has got a *bad* name. `if_else` (or `if_c`) would have been better?

Comment: @Quentin, It's a bit better in C++14: `std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>, AFancyIntVector, std::vector<T>>`

Comment: @chris I was rather referring to the emulation of specialization by means of branching :p

Answer (score 1):

It's neither possible to specialize them explicitly nor partially. [temp.decls]/3:

> Because an *alias-declaration* cannot declare a *template-id*, it is
>   not possible to partially or explicitly specialize an alias template.

You will have to defer specializations to class templates. E.g. with [`conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
template<typename T>
using YetAnotherVector = std::conditional_t< std::is_same<T, int>{}, 
                                             AFancyIntVector, 
                                             std::vector<T> >;
```

Comment: If you're using C++14, then you could avoid writing `::value` part as well, as `std::is_same<T,int>{}` is shorter!

Comment: @Nawaz I don't just care about shortness but also clarity. Anyway, if people find that readable, I'll edit the code appropriately

Comment: Umm, you do care about shortness, which is why you wrote `_t` version of `std::conditional`.

Comment: @Nawaz No, that is because of readability (=clarity). `conditional_t<…>` is more readable than `typename conditional<…>::type`, don't you think?

Comment: And you think `{}` version isn't better in terms of clarity? Think about lots of metaprogramming and the horizontal space it eats up!

Comment: @Nawaz I personally think `::value` expresses the intention more clearly, but that opinion will probably change rather soon. :)

Comment: Yes, it is likely your opinion will change soon. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is another pattern which I prefer over the std::conditional.  Maybe you'll prefer it as well.

It looks like this:

```
struct MyAwesomeVector {};

// this is the default 
template<typename T>
struct VectorSpecialization {
    typedef std::vector<T> Type;
} ;

// this is your awesomeness for int
template<>
struct VectorSpecialization<int> {
    typedef MyAwesomeVector Type;
} ;

// this is the using declaration
template<typename T>
using MyVector = typename VectorSpecialization<T>::Type;
```