# Using template alias over template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Reading a book [A tour of c++ (second edition), 2018](https://www.stroustrup.com/tour2.html), I didn't understand an explanation about templates (I'll explain below).

Two function signatures are given for a `find_all` function that returns a `vector` of `iterator`s to all occurrences of a given value in a given `container`.

#1 :

```
template<typename C, typename V>
vector<typename C::iterator> find_all(C& c, V v);
```

#2 :

```
template<typename T>
using Iterator = typename T::iterator;
template<typename C, typename V>
vector<Iterator<C>> find_all(C& c, V v) ;
```

Both can be used like this :

```
string m {"Mary had a little lamb"};
for (auto p : find_all(m,'a')) // here p is a string::iterator
    cout << *p << endl; // spoiler alert : this will print 'a's
```

The #2 using alias template is said to

> hide the implementation detail by introducing a type alias for Iterator

by the author.

Although I think I understand both usage of templates, I don't understand why would #2 "hide the implementation detail" and why it is preferred ... Can anyone explain me ?

Thanks !

Ps : I didn't provide the post with the definition of the functions (same for both signatures) because I think it isn't relevant, but I'll add it if anyone needs it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets say you have a code base like

```
template<typename C, typename V>
vector<typename C::iterator> first(C& c, V v);
template<typename C, typename V>
vector<typename C::iterator> second(C& c, V v);
template<typename C, typename V>
vector<typename C::iterator> third(C& c, V v);
template<typename C, typename V>
vector<typename C::iterator> fourth(C& c, V v);
...
```

If you decide you want to change to return a vector of `const_iterator` instead of `iterator`, you'd need to change all of those functions.  When using

```
template<typename T>
using Iterator = typename T::iterator;
template<typename C, typename V>
vector<Iterator<C>>  first(C& c, V v);
template<typename C, typename V>
vector<Iterator<C>>  second(C& c, V v);
template<typename C, typename V>
vector<Iterator<C>>  third(C& c, V v);
template<typename C, typename V>
vector<Iterator<C>>  fourth(C& c, V v);
```

all you would have to do is change

```
template<typename T>
using Iterator = typename T::iterator;
```

to

```
template<typename T>
using Iterator = typename T::const_iterator;
```

and you're done.  This is how it "hides the implementation detail".

Comment: See, I was thinking along those lines, but I was thinking of [specializing using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26844443/using-template-specialization), which apparently isn't a thing. That concept makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @limserhane: Also consider that you can have an arbitrarily complicated expression on the right side of `=` (so long as it results in a type). The alias usually turns it into a very simple and understandable type instead.